# using css, how to create a white circle within a transparent div?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I wish to create a white circle with fuzzy edges contained within a transparent div by using css gradients.

With the z-index higher than the body and absolute positioning I should be able to move this over any part of the page and "white-out" everything beneath the circle.

I have tried my favorite gradient generators, but they haven't worked.

Comment: Partial opacity background: `rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

Here's one I made using their tool: (Set the orientation to radial)

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+24,ffffff+59&1+31,0+34;Custom

To make the edges more fuzzy, drag the second opacity stop further from the white - and vice versa.

Comment: big fan of "Ultimate CSS Gradient Editor" myself.  I did not appreciate the opacity stops on top - thanks for the hint

Comment: @ccyoung They don't call it ultimate for nothing ;)

Answer (score 9):

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

css

```
#circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
}
```

Comment: then add box shadow and we're done - you're right - I was thinking too much!

Answer (score 1):

try white background with **box-shadow**'s **inset** property to create fuzzy edges. Although I don't get what fuzzy means to you. If you have a specific color in mind for the edges, I might be able to give you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Used the gradient suggested by George Reith.

CSS

```
#white-circle {
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center center , #FFFFFF 24%, #FFFFFF 31%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 34%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 71%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 100px;
left: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the outcome: http://jsbin.com/avipih/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess that radial gradient is an overkill for such purpose. Here's much simplier solution with better browser support: http://cdpn.io/yrJji